# Move HTML Table Borders Below child that is overflowing?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have a simple HTML Table in React with a div within the td.

```
<td style={{ minWidth: '50px', maxWidth: '50px' }}>
   <div style={{ width: '150px', zIndex: 9999}} >
      testing
   </div>
</td>
```

I want the div to overflow the cell, into the next few cells. However, the borders of the table are on top of the div. I can't figure out how to move the borders below the child div in CSS.
[image]

I tried z-index but it looks like it has no effect. Probably a noob question. Thanks!

Comment: Add `position:relative` on div `<div style={{ width: '150px', zIndex: 9999, position:relative}} >`

Comment: you need to set your position property to set your `z-index` property

Comment: Thanks everyone, this worked. knew it was something simple. @LaljiTadhani